# Port settings with Windows network related to receiving signal

Tags: windows, networking, port

I'm trying to run the same program on 2 laptops. One successfully ran the program but the other one could not. The following are the networks situation when I called the program.

From the below messages, I guess that it may be because the system is using the port.
The failed one cannot send anything from ports 2501 & 9301 while the successful one could do so (labelled with (*) & (**) below).

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

---

["netstat -na" on successful running]

```
Active Connections
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2501           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9301           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    212.14.156.113:2501     14.0.202.5:13362       ESTABLISHED ----(*)
  TCP    212.14.156.113:9301     14.0.202.5:2725        ESTABLISHED ----(**)
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                    
  UDP    212.14.156.113:1900     *:*
```

["netstat -na" on failed running]

```
Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2521           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2523           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2525           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2527           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9301           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    212.14.156.113:2512     173.252.122.23:443     ESTABLISHED
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:52555        *:*                    
  UDP    212.14.156.113:1900     *:*                    
  UDP    212.14.156.113:52554    *:*                    
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*
```

["netstat -a -b" on failed running]

```
 Active Connections
      Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
      TCP    0.0.0.0:2521           T61:0                  LISTENING
     [Program.exe]
      TCP    0.0.0.0:2523           T61:0                  LISTENING
     [Program.exe]
      TCP    0.0.0.0:2525           T61:0                  LISTENING
     [Program.exe]
      TCP    0.0.0.0:2527           T61:0                  LISTENING
     [Program.exe]
      TCP    0.0.0.0:9301           T61:0                  LISTENING
     [Program.exe]
      UDP    127.0.0.1:52555        *:*                    
      SSDPSRV
     [svchost.exe]
      UDP    212.14.156.113:52554    *:*                    
      SSDPSRV
     [svchost.exe]
      UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*                    
      SSDPSRV
     [svchost.exe]
```